# Load a javascript/ajax call on click using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, headless

I am trying to build a webscraper with which I can download the HTML source after information is received from a ajax call on click.
Simply speaking initially I download a the webpage and then on clicking the next button the page is loaded with a new set of images using a ajax call and I need to capture the html source after clicking next.

The next click source looks something like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return nextpage('xyz.html','2');" class="nextimage">Next Page</a>
```

And on the same page is the javascript function nextpage which handles the ajax call.

Is there a way to do this using phantomjs? I am very new to phantomjs so let me know if anything is not clear.
Currently I am only able to load the contents from original webpage.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('somewebpage', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
        });
        console.log(p);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

var content = page.evaluate( function() { return
(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString( document ); } );

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do I add this code snippet to the code given in the question?